# asp CompareValidator does not accept valid date

Tags: asp.net, comparevalidator

ASP CompareValidator with operator datatypecheck and datatype as date does not accept these dates: 3/29/2013 and 3/30/2012. Is this a known bug? Below is the validation.

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="comparevalidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="invalid date" Text="*" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date"  ControlToValidate="txtUserName"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: Validation is missing...

Answer (score 0):

this is depending on the regional settings of your webserver.

If you wish to overwrite these you can do this:

_ for all pages in web.config

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" />
```

_ for an individual page by setting the attributes of the @Page directive

```
<%@ Page UICulture="en-US" Culture="en-US" %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply , even so , it accepts 3/30/2013 or 3/28/2013 , but it does not accept 3/29/2013 , try it out.

Comment: Ok, tested both on a ASP.NET Development Server where regional settings are en-AU and  I had to set the @Page directive first and on a W2K3 server where regional settings are en-US. All three dates work. It accepts 3/28/2013, 3/29/2013 and 3/30/2013.